# Como trazer o nome dos campos e tipo de uma tabela oracle no c#

Tags: c#, oracle

Como eu faço para trazer o nome e tipo dos campos de uma tabela, usando Oracle e C#(WPF)?

Answer (score 1):

Esta query retorna os nomes e tipos de campos de uma tabela:

```
select COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE 
from ALL_TAB_COLUMNS 
where TABLE_NAME = 'NOME_TABELA'
```

Basta executá-la usando o seu mecanismo padrão de consultas SQL e ler o resultado.